# Science fiction book where each person has their own halation around their head?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about 20 years ago, and this is what I remember:

- It was science fiction. (Not fantasy, it was about people here in our world.)
- The protagonist could see [halation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halation) above the head of each person he saw, in different colors.
- The color and shape of the halation let him know about the person.
- This might have been horror book, but not sure, I don't remember the protagonist to be killing anyone but not sure about it.

Can anyone identify this book?

Comment: Did it involve a snowman too by any chance?

Comment: Does the term Kirlian ring any bells?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez it does ring a bell, but I'm not sure it's in same book sorry. It was really long ago...

Comment: @GerryColl nope, but thinking about it, I read Hebrew translation, so it might just have a different name.

Comment: See if it is on the list here or if something rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AuraVision

Comment: @jo1storm thanks, but don't see anything familiar there. I don't think that the book I read has made it to cinema.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 look in the literature section! Tvtropes is not only about cinema and tv, you know.

Comment: @jo1storm thanks, at first I just probed few of the examples and didn't find, however yesterday I decided to check them all and it's [Insomnia](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Insomnia). Can you please post answer? I was about to post a self answer, but on second thought, you deserve the credit. (and reputation. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insomnia is a novel written by Stephen King.

> Ralph Roberts, an elderly widower, is suffering from insomnia. Soon he
> begins to see things that are invisible to others—auras that represent
> people's life forces and little bald men who are present at the homes
> of the dying. Soon Ralph discovers that the fate of the universe is
> resting on his shoulders.

1. Seeing haloes - check.
2. Halo shape and color tells him about the person - check.
3. Horror book - check. Written by Stephen King no less.

Comment: Thanks, weird that I totally forgot about the little bald men. :)

Comment: science fiction, Not fantasy - no check